# How to get mybatis session factory from dispatcher-servlet xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mybatis, spring-mybatis

```
        <bean id="wspSqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="wspdataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/mybatis-config.xml"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="wspDao" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
        <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="wspSqlSessionFactory"/> 
        <property name="mapperInterface" value="com.lodige.clcs.dao.WSPDao" />
        </bean>
```

I wanted to access above `wspSqlSessionFactory` from java and below is the code:

```
      ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml");
           Object myBean = (SqlSessionFactory) ctx.getBean("dashbSqlSessionFactory");
           Configuration configuration = ((SqlSessionFactory) myBean).getConfiguration(); 
           Collection<Cache> caches = configuration.getCaches(); 
//Cache cache = configuration.getCache("src.main.domain.SysKeyEQ"); // namespace of particular XML
            //cache.clear();
           //If you have multiple caches and want a particular to get deleted.
            for (Cache cache : caches) { 
                System.out.println("cache Name:   "+caches);
                Lock w = cache.getReadWriteLock().writeLock(); 
                w.lock(); 
                try { 
                    //cache.clear(); 
                } finally { 
                    w.unlock(); 
                } 
       }
```

Am I doing it correctly to get the mybatis session or I need to it differently. And if I am doing correctly even if I have dispatcher-servlet in the above path still I get file not found exception. Even I just tried `"dispatcher-servlet.xml"`

**Possible Solution:**

```
          @Autowired
          @Qualifier("wspSqlSessionFactory")
          private SqlSessionFactoryBean  wspSqlSessionFactory;
           Configuration configuration = wspSqlSessionFactory.getObject().getConfiguration(); 
           Collection<Cache> caches = configuration.getCaches(); 
            for (Cache cache : caches) { 
                System.out.println("cache Name:   "+cache);
                Lock w = cache.getReadWriteLock().writeLock(); 
                w.lock(); 
                try { 
                    cache.clear(); 
                } finally { 
                    w.unlock(); 
                }
       }
```

Though I get caches and can clear them only if I remove

```
Lock w = cache.getReadWriteLock().writeLock(); 
   w.lock(); 
   try { 
   cache.clear(); 
   } finally { 
   w.unlock(); 
   }
```

and directly do `cache.clear();` else I get Null pointer exception in line: `Lock w = cache.getReadWriteLock().writeLock();` why is it NPE at that line is it okay/recommendable to not use Lock.

Comment: That is a horribly wrong way... Use dependency injection instead of recreating the context. You are basically loading your whole application again.

Comment: Any other way for getting ahold of the session object

Comment: As stated use dependency injection .

Comment: Sorry missed that. Please see the possible solution though I get caches alright and also clear if remove lock logic as I get error in line: `Lock w = cache.getReadWriteLock().writeLock(); ` I dont know I get Nullpointer exception in that line but I remove that and just clear cache it works fine.